# Why am I not required to specify type arguments in C#?

Tags: c#, generic-type-argument

I have a function that takes a generic type argument.  It's pretty simple:

```
private static void Run<T>(IList<T> arg)
{
    foreach (var item in arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

I've found that I can call this function without specifying the type argument:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    //both of the following calls do the same thing
    Run(list);
    Run<int>(list);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine.  Why does this work without specifying a type argument?  How does the code know that `T` is an int?  Is there a name for this?

Comment: This is because the compiler infers the type from the list<int> you passed in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type inference.

> The same rules for type inference apply to static methods and instance methods. The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method arguments you pass in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The compiler can infer the type from the argument you passed in..

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx):

> The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method
>   arguments you pass in; it cannot infer the type parameters only from a
>   constraint or return value

Eric Lippert also has an interesting read on overload selection with generics:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct. For more background information, here are some resources for you:

A video of me explaining how type inference changed in C# 3.0:

http://ericlippert.com/2006/11/17/a-face-made-for-email-part-three/

How do we know that the type inference process will not go into an infinite loop?

http://ericlippert.com/2012/10/02/how-do-we-ensure-that-method-type-inference-terminates/

Why are constraints not considered during type inference?  Read the comments in particular.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx